# Vue 3 prop returned as a string

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-props

I have a router link:

```
  <router-link
    :to="{
    name: 'EditStaff',
    params: { id: key, staffInfo: staff }
    }"
  >
    <i class="fas fa-edit text-info"></i>
  </router-link>
```

and a view with the following prop;

```
  props: {
    staffInfo: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  }
```

with a route;

```
  {
    path: "/staff/edit/:id",
    name: "EditStaff",
    component: EditStaff,
    props: true,
    beforeEnter: requireAuth
  },
```

When I log `props.staffInfo` in the EditStaff view, I am getting the string version of Object, `"[object Object]"`.

What do I need to change to get the object?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `console.log(props.staffInfo )` it may be converting your object to a string in-place

try `console.log(JSON.stringify(props.staffInfo ,null, 2))` instead

```js
const staffInfo = {gettingFired: 'false'};
console.log(staffInfo); // what you'd hope to get
console.log(staffInfo.toString()); // but you might be doing this, especially if it happens in the template
console.log(JSON.stringify(staffInfo).toString()); // so convert to string first
```

If you're trying to output it in the template, `{{ props.staffInfo }}` will be converted to use a `toString` (or equivalent)`

You can use `<pre>{{ JSON.stringify(props.staffInfo ,null, 2)) }}</pre>` to have nicer output.

Comment: I am getting the same results.

Comment: Is this in the template?

Comment: It's in the setup().

Comment: In the router link, I have changed the params to params: { id: key, staffInfo: JSON.stringify(staff ,null, 2) } and I am getting the expected results.